# pascal code to verify if a number contains all digits from 1 to 9 doesn't work

Tags: random, numbers, pascal, freepascal, digits

i wrote a pascal program that's supposed to verify if a number is composed of all the digits from 1 to 9 ( for example 123456789 or 987564123 ) but it's only works with 987654321 as an input (ie it displays 'yes'); i tried to use another code but nothing changed

```
program verify1 ;
Uses Wincrt ;
Var
  n,i,r,e : Longint;
Begin
  Readln(n);
  e := 0;
  For i:=1 To 9 Do
    Begin
      Repeat
        r := n Mod 10 ;
        n := n Div 10 ;
      Until (r=i) Or (n=0);
      If (r=i) Then e := e+1 ;
    End;
  If e=9 Then Writeln ('yes')
  Else Writeln ('no');
End.
```

```
Program verify2 ;
Uses Wincrt ;
Var
  n,i,r : Longint;
  condition: Boolean;
Begin
  Readln(n);
  i := 1;
  Repeat
    Repeat
      r := n Mod 10 ;
      n := n Div 10 ;
    Until (r=i) Or (n=0);
    If (r=i) Then
      Begin
        condition := True ;
        i := i+1 ;
      End
            else condition := false ; 
  Until (i=10) or ( condition = false );
  If condition=True Then Writeln ('yes');
  If condition = False Then Writeln ('no');
End.
```

Comment: The underlying algorithm you're using -- count how many of the digits from 1 to 9 inclusive appear in n and if the count is 9 then the number passes -- should work. However, you are modifying the variable `n` that contains this number each time through the loop. What you need is reset `n` to it's original value at the beginning of each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Why not debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you scan over the digits of a number and use those numbers to flip boolean values in an array from false to true to indicate whether they are present. If all values in indices 1 to 9 are true when we're done, then all digits are in the number.

```
program check_digits;
var
  test : array [0..9] of boolean = (
    false, false, false, false,
    false, false, false, false,
    false, false
  );
  n : longint;
  i : integer;
  found_all : boolean;

begin
  readln(n);

  while n > 0 do
  begin
    test[n mod 10] := true;
    n := n div 10;
  end;

  found_all := true;
  for i := 1 to 9 do
    if not test[i] then found_all := false;

  if found_all then
    writeln('All digits present.')
  else
    writeln('Some digits missing.');

end.
```

Comment: In Pascal, the _idiomatic_ solution would be to use a `set of 0..9`.
This also simplifies the check to an expression `if test = [1..9] then`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the sets functionality to hold the existence flags of all the digits. Purely mathematical solution:

```pascal
{$MODE OBJFPC}{$H+}

  function HasAllDigits(ANumber: Integer): Boolean;
  var
    Digits: set of 0 .. 9 = [];
  begin
    ANumber := Abs(ANumber);

    while ANumber > 9 do
    begin
      Digits  += [ANumber mod 10];
      ANumber := ANumber div 10;
    end;

    Digits += [ANumber];
    Result := Digits = [1 .. 9];
  end;

begin
  WriteLn(HasAllDigits(2137));       // False
  WriteLn(HasAllDigits(1234567890)); // True
end.
```

The second solution, based on strings:

```pascal
{$MODE OBJFPC}{$H+}

uses
  SysUtils;

  function HasAllDigits(ANumber: Integer): Boolean;
  var
    Digit:  Char;
    Digits: set of '0' .. '9' = [];
  begin
    for Digit in IntToStr(Abs(ANumber)) do
      Digits += [Digit];

    Result := Digits = ['1' .. '9'];
  end;

begin
  WriteLn(HasAllDigits(2137));       // False
  WriteLn(HasAllDigits(1234567890)); // True
end.
```

Comment: According to the question the requirements are “composed of all the digits from **1** to 9”. You are checking for _zero_ to nine. Besides I don’t really consider `+=` to be Pascal anymore.

Comment: The `+=` operator (and others) is built into Free Pascal and is part of the language. You may or may not consider it Pascal, but as long as it is officially supported by that dialect, it is officially Pascal. Anyway, these operators are useful and allow for shorter notation — there is nothing to be afraid of.

Comment: Well, support of `+=` and related depends on [`{$COperators on}` which by default are _off_](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.2.0/prog/progsu10.html). Maybe you should distribute your `fpc.cfg` containing the `‑Sc` switch, too, or at least include `{$COperators on}`?

Comment: `{$COPERATORS}` are `ON` by default in any newly created Lazarus project.